# Why would something vanish from credit report?

Tags: credit-score, credit-report, credit-history

I just got my Fico score (myFico.com) and was stunned when it was 67 points higher then 10 months ago (650 to 717).

I noticed it was missing a medical bill I still haven't paid from 2008 for around $1100. I checked my two other credit reports and it doesn't appear on either of those.

How is it possible that an item just vanishes from your report? Should I expect it to reappear?

Comment: Is it because the items get removed after a certain number of years (as the incident did happen 4 years ago in 2008)?

Comment: From everything I've read, things don't get removed from your credit report for 7 years.

Comment: 7 years is the maximum time it can stay on there, not the minimum.

Comment: The Bill must not have been reported. I would pay the thing as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Credit reports sometimes mess things up too. Since my father and I share names (I'm a II), I get a fair amount of stuff that are HIS on MY credit report.

For example, it will say *his* address as *my* current address which is inaccurate. Even after correcting it, it will usually revert within the year.

My point is, that there is a possibility that they are tying the debt to some other poor fellow who they are mistaking as you who hasn't noticed. (Although usually I've noticed it with one credit source, not all of them.)

Furthermore, the credit agency will only report what they are told to report, and it is possible the hospital has made a mistake and is reporting your account as paid up.